# R: Problem with calculating mean accuracy with strsplit function

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to calculate the accuracy of participants' response (columns `EQ_R` and `MEM_R`) based on the correct response (columns `EQ_C` and `MEM_C`).

```
dput(example) 
structure(list(TRIAL = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"), EQ_C = c("0101", "1010", 
"1010", "00111", "01011", "01101", "100011", "010101", "001101", 
"0110011", "1101001", "1100101", "11100001", "11001010", "11001010"
), EQ_R = c("0101", "0010", "1010", "00111", "01011", "01101", 
"10101", "11010", "001101", "0100011", "1101001", "0100101", 
"11110001", "11001010", "11001010"), MEM_C = c("ZLHK", "RZKX", 
"DGWL", "BCJSP", "WRKTJ", "CHBXS", "HNDCWX", "SWVNDT", "WLDGPB", 
"DSHRKBV", "HCXLZWB", "HDNBVZC", "BCRHKVDM", "RVTBWKFS", "NWHVZFLD"
), MEM_R = c("ZLHK", "RZKX", "DGWL", "BCJSP", "WRKLTJ", "CHBXS", 
"HNDCWX", "SWVDTN", "WLDGPB", "DSHRKBV", "HCXLZWB", "HDNBVZC", 
"BCRHKVDM", "RVTBWKFS", "NWHVZFLD"), EQ_SUM = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), MEM_SUM = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names             
 = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

I added a new column for the "sum"/accuracy scores that need to be calculated for the binary data (EQ) and letters (MEM).

```
    OSPAN["EQ_SUM"] <- NA
    OSPAN["MEM_SUM"]<- NA
```

I then tried to calculate the accuracy with strsplit, but I receive error notifications.

```
    mean(strsplit(OSPAN$MEM_C, "") == strsplit(OSPAN$MEM_R, ""))
    Error in strsplit(OSPAN$MEM_C, "") == strsplit(OSPAN$MEM_R, "") : comparison of these types is not implemented
    In addition:
    Warning messages:
    1: In strsplit(OSPAN$MEM_R, "") : input string 342 is invalid                             UTF-8
    2: In strsplit(OSPAN$MEM_R, "") : input string 580 is invalid UTF-8
```

My question is:

How do I match/calculate the accuracy or congruence between predictor (C) and actual (R) values into the sum columns?

For instance, in row #1, `EQ_SUM` would be 1 (or 100%), whereas it would be 0.75 or 75% in #2, as the participant chose the wrong answer (0 instead of 1). Thus, partial credit scores are given, and it is not a matter of absolute match/congruence.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `strsplit()` produces a list.

Comment: do you have any idea what I could use instead? I was thinking of importing the list into the original data frame after I calculated the accuracy scores for each row.

Comment: @annedroid what if R and C are in different length e.g. EQ_C and EQ_R in row 7 and 8

Comment: I tried to address this question in the answer below, but have not found a conclusive answer yet. Do you maybe have an idea? @A.Suliman

Comment: @annedroid here are two options using `base::adist` 1. `apply(OSPAN, 1, function(x) adist(x['EQ_C'], x['EQ_R']))` which will produce the difference in terms of number, 2. or you can normalize thses numbers using `min` or `max`, e.g: `apply(OSPAN, 1, function(x) (max(nchar(x['EQ_C']), nchar(x['EQ_R'])) - adist(x['EQ_C'], x['EQ_R']))/max(nchar(x['EQ_C']), nchar(x['EQ_R'])))`

Answer (score 2):

One possibility could be using the `RecordLinkage` library:

```
with(df, levenshteinSim(EQ_C, EQ_R))

 [1] 1.0000000 0.7500000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.6666667 0.6666667
 [9] 1.0000000 0.8571429 1.0000000 0.8571429 0.8750000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

It calculates the similarity between the two strings using the Levenshtein distance.

Comment: This has actually helped a lot, thank you! Especially since the way I calculated the Levensthein distance in the original post did not work due to encoding reasons. I assume [1] and [9] just show the results for row 1 and 9 as an example?

Comment: Yes, that is just the row number.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there is a most efficient way, however, you can compare list by list and add it to your data frame.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(OSPAN)){
  OSPAN$EQ_SUM[i] <- sum(strsplit(OSPAN$EQ_C, "", useBytes = TRUE)[[i]] == strsplit(OSPAN$EQ_R, "", useBytes = TRUE)[[i]])/length(strsplit(OSPAN$EQ_C, "")[[i]])
  OSPAN$MEM_SUM[i] <- sum(strsplit(OSPAN$MEM_C, "", useBytes = TRUE)[[i]] == strsplit(OSPAN$MEM_R, "", useBytes = TRUE)[[i]])/length(strsplit(OSPAN$MEM_C, "")[[i]])
}
```

On the other hand, there are cases with different length, what do we do with them?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the valuable help! When I run this code, I receive warnings for each row: 

    In strsplit(OSPAN$MEM_R, "") : input string 342 is invalid UTF-8
 
Can I change the encoding before using strsplit?

Comment: Adding the argument ```useBytes = TRUE``` at ```strsplit``` should handle this issue. However, what do we do when both comparisons have different lengths?
I'm modifying my answer with what I told you.

Comment: I tried the edited code with `useBytes = TRUE` at `strsplit` but unfortunately now receive the following error code: 
`longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`. Which brings me to your second question ... I was thinking that I could set the string length to N = 10, adding some sort of dummy characters to all strings. I would then somehow cut the strings according to a predefined rule (if possible), such as: rows 1:3 - length of 4 characters, rows 4:7 - length of 5 characters and so on and so forth. That would probably be a loop, I assume? Sorry to bother you with this!

Comment: Although the error message, it makes the calculus. Check the dataframe OSPAN. (It says how many R = C, if there are more C than R, it assumes that the difference is an incorrect answer).

Comment: And yes, It would be a loop. But is not necessary to do that.
IF C >= R, then, what you have to do is supress the last values of C until C = R.